# Strange delay sending email via SMTP on Exchange 2003

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, exchange-2003

When I try to send email through Exchange 2003 via an SMTP connection, I get a strange delay after specifying the recipient.  Here is a telnet log, with a redacted domain name: (telnet mail.xxx.com 25)

```
220 mail.xxx.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 5.0.2195.6713 ready at  Fri, 16 Oct 2009 09:42:20 -0500
HELO
250 mail.xxx.com Hello [172.16.128.42]
MAIL FROM: dms@xxx.com
250 2.1.0 dms@xxx.com....Sender OK
RCPT TO: ttheisen@xxx.com
```

After a delay of a minute or so, (it seems to vary) I get this:

```
250 2.1.5 ttheisen@xxx.com
```

Although the exact delay varies, it's always a significant delay.

However, when I repeat this exact same transaction from our intranet server, there is zero noticeable delay.  I'm really more of a software developer than an admin, and I just can not figure this out.

Anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you an admin of this Exchange 2003 server, do you have access to the configuration? It could be a few things:

- Antispam mitigation, some servers add a delay onto the transaction to slow down spammers. AKA [Tarpitting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842851).
- If domain resolution is being done during this process, it is possible there is a problem with resolving xxx.com.
- Some other custom program or processing done on the recipient email address.

Comment: It's not tar pitting, as this is Windows 2k.  Since these are all the same internal domain, I don't understand how it could be name resolution, but I'll check on the other two.

Thanks for the good leads.

Comment: Exchange 2003 includes a tarpitting option (regardless of underlaying OS). What you stated sounds exactly like tarpitting, I would really check there first. Might be under some sort of "anti directory harvesting" option.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  Not positive it's tar pitting yet, but I have found that authenticating the session eliminates the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that Exchange is doing a reverse DNS lookup (PTR) on your client address to check that you are who you say you are. Using NSLOOKUP from the exchange server, can you get a PTR record returned from 172.16.128.42?  If not, that is most likely the reason for the long pause...